# Puppeteer, ExpressJS, React SSR

Tags: reactjs, express, puppeteer, server-side-rendering

i am trying to achieve Server Side Rendering aka SSR for my react app. I created an `express` app with puppeteer and got endpoint with following snippets.

```
const port = 3003
app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        const local_url = `http://localhost:${port}${req.originalUrl}`;
        await page.goto(local_url, {
            waitUntil: "networkidle0",
        });
        const html = await page.content()
        await browser.close()
        res.send(html);

    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.send("ERROR");
    }
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
    console.log(`Web run ${port}`);
});
```

I just don't know why this is not working. Do I have to run my react app(run on `3000`) separate and point `local_url` variable to there? like

```
const local_url = `http://localhost:3000${req.originalUrl}`;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not working"?

Comment: @Everettss well, when i load the page and check `source` of page it should include all the react component as html tag right? thing does not.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a loop where you are requesting same url over and over.
Your react app is in port 3000, and this express app is in port 3003. 
You can make things a bit easy to read if you seperate them.

You have to run the react server on port 3000 and point to that otherwise it won't know where to browse.

```
const react_port = 3000;
const server_port = 3003;
const local_url = `http://localhost:${react_port}${req.originalUrl}`;
```

and vice varsa.